# General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'

Tags: laravel, migration

I don't understand why I am receiving this error because I don't use reference in `users` table. The following migration is for user table:

```
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->integer('hostname_id')->default(0)->unsigned();
        $table->integer('main_role_id')->default(2)->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger('phone')->default('+37360000000');
        $table->string('job_title');
        $table->integer('photo_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index()->default(1);
        $table->date('birth_date');
        $table->boolean('enabled')->default(true);
        $table->integer('points')->default(0);
        $table->integer('experience')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and I am receiving this error :

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: create table `users` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(191) not null, `password` varchar(191) not null, `email` varchar(191) not null, `hostname_id` int unsigned not null default '0', `main_role_id` int unsigned not null default '2', `phone` bigint not null default '+37360000000', `job_title` varchar(191) not null, `photo_id` int unsigned null default '1', `birth_date` date not null, `enabled` tinyint(1) not null default '1', `points` int not null default '0', `experience` int not null default '0', `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

Comment: Your default phone number looks more of a string than an integer. try change the type to string

Comment: Didn't work, can be the problem in the model?

Comment: before you get to the model, are you able to migrate this table into your databasa?

Comment: no, I can't do migrate

Comment: To be honest, you can comment out field one by one and migrate after each one trying to narrow it down. Maybe the issue isn't even here. To me it looks like some table is referenced before it is created, so the order of migrations is wrong.

Comment: Sorry i cant copy and try your code but try commenting out the phone and photo columns and rerun migrate. the other lines look ok and those ones are suspicious

Comment: It's weird, I comment every column and left only id and timestamp, and still have error  `General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint`

Comment: @Marius What other migration files you have?

Comment: Run composer-dump autoload and try again

Comment: I tried and I have the same error

Comment: I left only id column and timestamp and I have this error: `General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: create table users (id bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci`